# How to create a function with one paramter that will blur an image in php

Tags: php, imagemagick, blur

I'm using Image Magick for php (function [Imagick::blurImage](https://www.php.net/manual/pl/imagick.blurimage.php)) and it have 2 paramters radius and sigma. How can I calculate those 2 paramters based on percentage of the blur.

what I need is a function

```
function blur($image, $percent) {
   // how to calculate sigma and radius
}

$image = new Imagick($_GET['image']);
blur($image, $_GET['blur']);
echo $image;
```

Comment: please blur using js or css .html5 canvas also is good

Comment: @ArunKillu it need to work in every browser. IE don't have canvas and only Webkit have css blur, and I'm using Rafael.js for transformation.

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem? Have you tried throwing different numbers at each parameter to see what they generate?

Comment: @Charles I try to modify one argument and have another constant and I also try to use $percent/10 and $percent%10

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase.  Have you experimented to see what each of the two arguments *does*?  Keep sigma steady while varying the radius, how much does the blur change?  You have not demonstrated that you have tried to solve this problem on your own.

Comment: @Charles I notice that if sigma is larger then radius the blur is not changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out I use both the same.

```
function blur($image, $percent) {
   $blur = $percent*20/100;
   $image->gaussianBlurImage($blur, $blur);
}
```